# How to change img content after selecting a drop-down

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to change the content of my image after selecting the drop-down list. But after choosing the active pseudo-class it's blinking all the time.
I've tried many pseudo-classes so far but none of them worked. 
Could anyone tell me what I did wrong?

```
var expanded = false;
function showCheckboxes() {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
    if (!expanded) {
        checkboxes.style.display = "block";
        expanded = true;
    } else {
        checkboxes.style.display = "none";
        expanded = false;
    }
}
```

Here is the live

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
  width: 100px;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px gray solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100px !important;
}

.select-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.drop-arrow {
  content: url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cursor.png");
}

.selectBox:active .drop-arrow {
  content: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/change_password.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="multiselect">
  <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
    <div class="select-container">
      <select>
        <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
      <img class="drop-arrow" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="overSelect"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="checkboxes">
    <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one">First checkbox</label>
    <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" id="two">Second checkbox</label>
    <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three">Three checkbox</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get the thing that you wanna do, I this case I dont would use pseudo elements, I rather use classes, and you can toggle that clase using jquery or javascript, you can create a class called "active" and then when you click in the drop down you can change the image (you need to use css and putting the desired image as a background property) It would work

Comment: Is it possible to do this with pure javascript?

Comment: @Daenerys ofc :)

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but your code will be a little longer instead using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

friend the problem is with selectBox:active .drop-arrow it only works when clic is pressed for that you can do like the code bellow; and another problem I saw you must to add  flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis to childs of flex container in this case .select-container, This code can be inprove with jquery toogleclass() check it

```js
var expanded = false;
function showCheckboxes() {
 var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
 if (!expanded) {
  checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    $(".select-container div").removeClass("drop-arrow");
    $(".select-container div").addClass("drop-arrow2");
  expanded = true;
 } else {
    $(".select-container div").removeClass("drop-arrow2");
    $(".select-container div").addClass("drop-arrow");
  checkboxes.style.display = "none";
  expanded = false;
 }
}
```

```css
.multiselect {
 width: 140px;
}

.selectBox {
 position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}

#checkboxes {
 display: none;
 border: 1px gray solid;
}

#checkboxes label {
 display: block;
}

#checkboxes label:hover {
 background-color: yellow;
}

select {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 text-indent: 1px;
 text-overflow: '';
 background-color: transparent;
 flex:1 0 auto;
}
.select-container {
 display: flex;
 background-color: gray;
  width:auto; 
}


.drop-arrow {
flex:1 0 auto;
display:block;
width: 50px;
height: 35px;
background-image:url("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/cursor.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
   
}

.drop-arrow2 {
 content: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32/change_password.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiselect">
    <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
     <div class="select-container">
      <select>
       <option>Select an option</option>
      </select>
            <div class="drop-arrow" alt=""></div>
     </div>
     
     <div class="overSelect"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="checkboxes">
     <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one">First checkbox</label>
     <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" id="two">Second checkbox</label>
     <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three">Three checkbox</label>
    </div>
   </div>
```

check my pen https://codepen.io/Qleoz12/pen/QzPQvp